# Visual Studio 2008;: adding a webreference

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, reference

Aloha

I have a VS2008 solution to which I want to add a webservice reference. I enter an url like 'http://192.168.100.87:7001/wsdl/IMySOAPWebService'. The Add Web Reference dialog starts looking then throws me this error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://192.168.100.87:7001/wsdl/IMySOAPWebService/$metadata'.

Adding the exact same reference to a VS 2005 project works fine. Any clues?

Comment: When you say it works in VS2005 - is that on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aloha,

I've solved this by using the (VS2008) `svcutil.exe` This generated a proxy for me with no troubles

Answer (score 1):

ASMX?  Have you made sure you are using the correct dialog to enter a standard web reference?  By default, VS2008 hides this option, only allowing a WCF service reference.  If you look at the bottom of the dialog, you'll see a button or checkbox (don't have 2008 in front of me) to allow adding an ASMX service reference.

**EDIT**

Found it - Right click on your project -> Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference

That's where you'll find the correct dialog for adding an ASMX service